# Закрытие и создание модального окна

Tags: javascript, html, css, окно

А как закрыть модальное окно (без помощи `display:none`)

Не так как ниже

```js
let modal = document.getElementsByClassName('modal')[0];
let modalcontent = document.getElementsByClassName('modal-content')[0];
let loginlink = document.getElementById('loginlink');

let elemclose = document.getElementsByClassName("closeregwindow")[0];

loginlink.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "inline-block";
}


elemclose.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="closeregwindow">&times;</span>
      <h2>Вход или регистрация</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="contentreg">
        <p class="username"><b>Логин</b></p>
        <div class="eleminput">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Логин" class="inputusername">
        </div>
        <p class="username"><b>Пароль</b></p>
        <div class="eleminput">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Пароль" class="inputusername">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--
      <p>Какой-то текст в теле модального окна</p>
      <p>Ещё другой текст...</p>-->
      <div class="loginbuttons">
        <div class="loginbtnitem1">
          <button type="submit" class="loginbtn">Войти</button>
        </div>
        <div class="loginbtnitem2">
          <button type="submit" class="registrationbtn">Регистрация</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Футер модального окна</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

т. е. не с помощью

```
    elemclose.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Иными словами нужно не спрятать, а нужно закрыть окно - возможно обновление
главного окна или еще какие-нибудь способы.

Answer (score 0):

```
elemclose.addEventListener(`click`, e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal.remove();
});
```

Comment: @krasnodarprogrammer раз оно есть в html, то соответственно уже создано.

Comment: `loginlink.onclick = function(){modal.style.display: block;}` не отобразит окно (**при втором открытии**), т. к. оно было удалено.

Comment: правильно ли понимаю, что `modal.remove` удаляет код модального окна `modal` из `html`?

Comment: @krasnodarprogrammer неужели так сложно заглянуть в [документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)?